# How do you design a circuit to implement the Bipolar Line coding Technique?

Tags: digital-logic, design, digital-communications, encoding

Bipolar NRZ
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_communication_computer_network/images/bipolar.jpg

[image]

In this technique alternate 1's will have alternate polarities and 0's will be zero itself.

Comment: Hint: Such circuits are often transformer-coupled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture and description: -

[image]

Taken from [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QV_l-oMHXDMC&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=alternate+mark+inversion+schematic&source=bl&ots=6oG23SAjCj&sig=d93qdPAW5aIqqg4C-NS8-VmvHtY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jPI4VcyZFsy7aaqtgLAP&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=alternate%20mark%20inversion%20schematic&f=false). Below is a better view of the circuit taken from another website: -

[image]

From [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=alternate+mark+inversion+schematic&biw=1280&bih=897&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=a_I4VfXlN8vbaIm-gOAH&ved=0CAUQ_AUoAA&dpr=1)

Comment: Yeah, I've actually tried these circuits out but there is a synchronization problem between the 3 input waves which are being provided. Any idea on how this could be rectified?

Comment: You hold all the cards on this. Explain in detail what the problem is and maybe draw a waveform picture to add clarity. I think that this would have been a better question because it would have avoided me wasting my time on something you've already tried. Disclosure of what you have tried is not only important but shows respect.

Comment: Well, I've actually tried/ simulated these circuits only after   I've seen these circuits here!
So yeah, your answer was actually partially helpful!